# IDX10632: SymmetricSecurityKey.GetKeyedHashAlgorithm( 'HS512' ) threw an exception when validating JWT using HS512 ALGO

Tags: c#, security, encoding, jwt, identity

I'm using the NuGet package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version 4.0.4.403061554.

I have an implementation that validates a JWT and it works fine for algo HS256.

However if I change my JWT to be generated using algo HS512 then I receive an error during validation.

```
System.IdentityModel.SignatureVerificationFailedException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey
'.
Exceptions caught:
 'System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10632: SymmetricSecurityKey.GetKeyedHashAlgorithm( 'HS512' ) threw an exception.
SymmetricSecurityKey: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey'
SignatureAlgorithm: 'HS512', check to make sure the SignatureAlgorithm is supported.
```

I've tried to generate 512 bit keys, I've also tried smaller keys like 256 bit keys (the ones that work with algo HS256) but nothing works.

My implementation is this:

```
                    InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey signingKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secretsigningkey"));
                    TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudiences = validAudiences,
                        ValidIssuers = validIssuers,
                        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey
                    };
                    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
```

and the exception is thrown by this method **tokenHandler.ValidateToken**.

How can I change my code to allow for HS512 (and any other type of JWT supported algos)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I landed up upgrading the version of the package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to 6.7.1 (probably unnecessary).

The real fix was changing this:

```
InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey signingKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secretsigningkey"));
```

to this

```
SecurityKey signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(domainJWTParams.IssuerSigningKey));
```

This works with HS256, HS384, HS512 (possibly even more) but what's really good with this implementation is that no hardcoded algorithm is needed.

Answer (score 2):

1. According to this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.securityalgorithms?view=netframework-4.8) document, `SecurityAlgorithms` doesn't support validating HS512 algorithm.

2. Install the jwt decode/validation library : `JWT` and it's project site: https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt

```sh
PM> Install-Package JWT -Version 7.2.1
```

3. Use the `JWT` official document and modify your sample code by using HS512 algorithm, it will be like this:

```cs
try
{
    IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
    var provider = new UtcDateTimeProvider();
    IJwtValidator validator = new JwtValidator(serializer, provider);
    IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
    IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new HMACSHA512Algorithm();
    IJwtDecoder decoder = new JwtDecoder(serializer, validator, urlEncoder, algorithm);

    json = decoder.Decode(token, "secretsigningkey", verify: true);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
catch (TokenExpiredException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Token has expired");
}
catch (SignatureVerificationException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Token has invalid signature");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Other exception: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Your solution does work strictly for HMACSHA512 however I was really trying to get an implementation using the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt package if possible and also a way to be flexible with algorithms.